# object has no attribute all django

Tags: django, model, attributes, admin, nonetype

I am trying to reuse an existant Django project, which works just fine, but I encounter an error on a specific part. I'm only using the admin interface with quite a few models. The error is as follow :

Whenever I try to add an object (of this particular model) via the admin, I get :

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'all'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/myapp/style/add/
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'all'
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py in __iter__, line 919
```

I found the "NoneType" in the admin.py :

```
class StyleForm(forms.ModelForm):

        featured_item = forms.ModelChoiceField(None, required=False)
```

and in the models.py :

```
def featured_item_id(self):

    fi_list = FeaturedItem.objects.filter(style=self)

    if fi_list.count() > 0:
        return fi_list[0].item.id
    else:
        return None
```

I would understand that such an error is possible if the project had never worked and wasn't working at this very moment elsewhere, but this is a functionnal Django project, all I did was migrate it locally, fixing the settings.py accordingly... Could it come from the database not being populated at the moment ?

I would very much appreciate any help, I've been stuck with it for quite a while and it's important that I manage to get past this annoying bug..

Thank you all in advance for your time and advice.

Comment: It could probably be some cached compiled files which were working fine. Seems wierd though. You probably wanted `forms.ModelChoiceField(FeaturedItem.objects.none(), required=False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marking the comment as an answer for future reference:

It could probably be some stale `.pyc` files which were working fine. Seems wierd though. You probably wanted

```
forms.ModelChoiceField(FeaturedItem.objects.none(), required=False)
```